# Installing Matplotlib, Numpy, Pylab, Etc on Mac

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm using Mac OS 10.8.3.  I've spent hours trying to install matplotlib and can't get this to work.

All I want to be able to do is:

from pylab import *

and then plot two simple arrays.  I know I need to change the default python on mac, to no avail.  Generally I download a make package for something like matplotlib, it tells me it installs correctly and then I can't import pylab.

Anyway, if anyone can help I would be very much indebted.  I don't understand why installing something has to be so complicated.

Comment: It always help to post what you have tried explicitly in your question.

Comment: The easy way is to install Canopy from Enthought

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) to install python and pip to install matplotlib. There is a good tutorial [here](http://www.lowindata.com/2013/installing-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score 2):

use easy install.

```
sudo easy_install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php) to install [matplotlib](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/python/py-matplotlib/Portfile), which would take care of all dependencies.  Note the possible port variants for various backends.